# how to use an image in gesture detector 3 rows and 3 columns for tic tac toe so that my logic works for the image in. Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, grid, gesturedetector

```
Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 9,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _tapped(index);
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    displayXorO[index],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: logic works fine but i want to put an image of tic tac toe in the grid so that it works for the image flutter

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve ? Just putting an image and then putting your actual widget on top of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use stack with image at the bottom and thn use grid view logic on top of it .